# Formula Error - duplicate dimensions across (independent) axes - in a <uple> base object

Tags: mdx, cube

The following is giving me the error in the title. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 SELECT  ([Day].Children ) ON ROWS, 
 ([Month].Children ) ON COLUMNS FROM myCube
 WHERE ([Measures].[Humidity], [Measures].[Temp], [Year].[2010])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd expect a different error given that you have Measures repeated in the WHERE clause.

On the surface, I can't explain the other error yet, but I wonder what it would look like if you shared the complete unique names instead of [Day], [Month] and [Year].